# How to load a shapefile in BigQuery? Is there a simpler way to upload polygon data in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, gis

I have been trying to load polygon data in BigQuery, but it doesnt seem to work.

Is there any simpler way to upload polygon data in BigQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to find a simple solution! :)

```
# First, I convert the shapefile to a geojson:
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 data/poligonos_setores_censitarios.geojson data/pr_setores_censitarios

# After, since BigQuery demands json and geojson files to be newline delimited, I modify it a bit:
cat data/poligonos_setores_censitarios.geojson | jq -c ".features[]" > data/poligonos_setores_censitarios_newlinedelimited.geojson

# Then, I upload it to Google Cloud Storage:
gsutil cp data/poligonos_setores_censitarios_newlinedelimited.geojson gs://cloud-storage-bucket01/

# And finally, load it in BigQuery:
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --json_extension=GEOJSON --autodetect mydataset.polygons gs://cloud-storage-bucket01/poligonos_setores_censitarios_newlinedelimited.geojson
```

Comment: Nice, yes, schema management is simpler now with new-line-delimited-geojson support. You can probably skip `jq` too by exporting to ND-GeoJson directly, org2org supports it with `-f GeoJSONSeq` option

Comment: Btw if you already have a GeoJSON, only it's not newline delimited, use `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSONSeq file_newlinedelimited.geojson file.geojson` (instead of the first 2 lines in the answer)